# How to use onEdit trigger to produce timestamp in a dynamic cell using vlookup?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm trying to build a glorified to-do list for posting to various job boards. I have a sheet with all website properties, including a unique ID for each property, as well as columns for when the most recent post was submitted (where the timestamp will land). The to-do list is a tab called Posting Tasks, and includes the same unique ID, as well as a checkbox to mark that post as complete.

[Database tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNG4v.png)

I'm using the onEdit trigger to produce a timestamp on the Database sheet (column K) when cells in Column A of Posting Tasks sheet are 'true'. However, the timestamps are fixed to the row of the corresponding trigger. I'd like them to be relative based on a matching (vlookup) of the unique ID (column C in the trigger sheet, and column B in the Database sheet), since the Posting Tasks sheet changes daily.

[Posting tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY8kV.png)

I'm using the below script, but don't know how to change the `e.range.rowStart` to be relative and lookup corresponding values. Any ideas?

```
function onEdit(e) {

    var sheetsToWatch= ['Posting Tasks', 'Database'
                      ],
        columnToWatch = 1,
        columnToStamp = 11;           

    if (e.range.columnStart !== columnToWatch
      || sheetsToWatch.indexOf( e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() ) === -1 
      || !e.value)
        return;
    e.source.getSheetByName('Database')
        .getRange(e.range.rowStart, columnToStamp)
        .setValue(new Date());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('flag1');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var name=sh.getName();
  if(name=='Posting Tasks' && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value) {
    e.source.toast('flag2');
    var id=e.range.offset(0,2).getValue();
    var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName('Database');
    var idA=tsh.getRange(3,2,tsh.getLastRow()-2,1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0]});
    var row=idA.indexOf(id)+3;
    var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName('Database').getRange(row,11).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
  }
}
```

Andrew Karp Modification:

```
var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 
if (sh.getName() !== 'Posting Tasks' || e.range.columnStart !== 1 || e.range.rowStart < 3 || e.value !== 'TRUE') return; 
e.range.offset(0, 0).clearContent() } }
```

Comment: Amazing, that worked! Thank you! There's a formatting issue on the Database tab (the timestamp is read as text, not date), but I'm assuming that's a simple fix.

Comment: Follow up, if anyone is interested, I added a clear content to @Cooper 's solution. This removes the checkbox as soon as it's been checked, bumping the next task to the top of the list with an unchecked box:
  `var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if (sh.getName() !== 'Posting Tasks' || e.range.columnStart !== 1 || e.range.rowStart < 3 || e.value !== 'TRUE') return;
    e.range.offset(0, 0).clearContent()
  }
}`